# Is this Change of Variable Theorem fine as it is, or should we specify the domain that $f$ is continuous on?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definition

One of my instructors provided me with the following Change of Variable Theorem:

> Let $a < b$.
>
> Let $f$ be a continuous function.
>
> Let $g$ be a function with a continuous derivative on $[a, b]$.
>
> Assume the range of $g$ on $[a, b]$ is contained in the domain of $f$.
>
> Then,
>
> $$\int_a^b f(g(x)) g'(x) \, dx = \int_{g(a)}^{g(b)} f(u) \, du$$

I was wondering if it's sufficient to say "let $f$ be a continuous function" as above.

Shouldn't we specify $f$ to be continuous on $[a, b]$? Because a function being continuous means it's continuous on its domain, and if the domain is not specified, there's no guarantee that it'll be continuous on $[a, b]$, and therefore the last line would not be a well-defined expression.

Comment: I have always interpreted general statements like "$f$ is continuous" to mean that $f$ is continuous on the whole space that you are considering, usually $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @TonyS.F. In this particular course, the instructor is usually very precise, and has taken great care to foster a similar precision in me. If we wanted to be precise, we would have to specify an explicit domain, correct? Otherwise $f$ could be defined on an interval $I$ that is outside of $[a, b]$, and the theorem would be meaningless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we write “$f$ is continuous” it is implied that we mean $f$ is continuous on its domain.

Note that it is *not* sufficient to say $f$ is continous on $[a,b]$. Rather, we need $f$ to be continuous on $g([a,b]) =\{y\mid y=g(x), x\in[a,b]\}$.

Comment: I disagree that it's implied $f$ is continuous on its domain. if this were the case, then the function $1/x$ would be continuous, since $0$ is not in its domain to begin with. however, i don't think anyone would say that $1/x$ is a continuous function (without specifying *where* it's continuous).

Comment: I mentioned the implication in the last paragraph of my post. Furthermore, I believe the given definition takes into account that $f$ is continuous on $g([a, b])$ by the assumption that the range of $g$ on $[a, b]$ is contained in the domain of $f$. My question is whether it's sufficient to say that $f$ is continuous on its domain without specifying an explicit domain.

Comment: @TonyS.F. That very example caused a *huge* debate among some calculus instructors at my university... there certainly *are* mathematicians who would say $1/x$ is continuous because it is continuous on its domain. Strictly speaking, the definition of continuity of a function $f:X \to Y$ says that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$ for every $x_0 \in X$, so indeed this would say that $1/x$ is continuous.

Comment: @Calculemus As I mentioned in my answer, we do not need $f$ to be continuous on $[a,b]$. We need it to be continuous on $g([a,b])$, which it is since $g([a,b]) \subseteq \text{dom}(f)$.The domain of $f$ does not need to be explicitly stated, but it does need to contain $g([a,b])$.

Comment: @kccu Okay, I think I understand now. The domain of $f$ is the range of $g$ on $[a, b]$, which is specified in the theorem. So the theorem is fine as it is. Thanks for bearing with me.